# Equivalent of `/etc/init/` folder for non admin users?

Tags: server, permissions, sync, remote, init

We have a cluster where I run some simulations. I want automatically sync the results between multiple computers so I decided to use syncthing.

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-syncthing-to-synchronize-directories-on-ubuntu-14-04) setting up syncthing on the headless server. at some point it asks to make a file `syncthing.conf` in the folder `/etc/init/` but I don't have admin privileges to create/edit files and folders there:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘init’: Permission denied

I was wondering if there is a non-admin equivalent for the `/etc/init/` folder where I can put this file and it function as expected.

P.S.1. My tags are probably wrong. I don't know what tags are appropriate for this question. I would appreciate if moderators can help me with that.

P.S.2. the machine operating system is:

```
Linux foobar 4.4.0-128-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 14:15:18 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It is a cluster where I'm running some simulations. I want to use syncthing to sync files across some machines. is it clear now?

Comment: @user535733 I added more information. I would appreciate if you could help me know if it is ok now.

Comment: If it syncs every half an hour it is fine. but the issue is that my local machine is Windows. plus there are multiple machines including my laptops. Syncthing syncs all of them at the same time and has an android app too. So I prefer to use this. but if there are other options to sync files reliably between multiple machines, including windows platform, please let me know.

Comment: That's important to know. That whole paragraph needs to be in your question so you get useful answers!

Comment: @user535733 sure. but the question should be changed then.on a side note I think if I change the default folder of `upstart` program as described [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)

Comment: I'm trying to compile it locally.

Comment: If you don't have sudo access, why don't you just use rsync at regular intervals using cron?

Comment: @Ray running rsync on multiple computers manually is annoying. syncthing should do that automatically plus other options like conflict management and version control ...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Foad I suppose so...  Though the word "annoying" is relative.  After you've set up rsync and cron, you don't have to worry about it any more.  And, you don't need sysadmin access, which appears to be one of your problems now. As for your question, I think what you want/need is actually syncthing to not need administrator rights.  Thus, I have a feeling you should ask your question to the syncthing [forum](https://forum.syncthing.net/) if no one here can answer your question.  It isn't an Ubuntu issue; if syncthing doesn't allow it, I doubt the Ubuntu package of it will.

Comment: @Ray how can I do that automatically? I mean is there anyway that rsync syncs all the files automatically in the intervals?

Comment: @muru added to the P.S.2.

Comment: @Foad that's probably Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm not sure. Try `lsb_release -cd`

Comment: @muru no it is `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS xenial`

Comment: @Ray I posted the question [here on their forum](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/how-to-install-syncthing-on-aheadless-cluster-without-admin-privialages/12178) as well.

Comment: @Foad Oh!  It seems that you are getting some help already...  I don't know how many syncthing users are here and your question sounded to me like it was specific to how syncthing works.  Good luck with that!

Comment: @Foad About your earlier question, like I suggested, you can use cron .  Type `man 5 crontab` to see the format of the file.  And run `crontab -e` to edit your crontab.  You can make it run `rsync` at regular intervals but you can't make it sync whenever a file has been changed...that's where you would have to use syncthing.